# error when running checkbox in listview android

Tags: android, mysql, database, listview, checkbox

when i was trying tutorial checkbox in listview theres some error on my adapter

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewTag viewTag;

    if (convertView == null) {
        //取得listItem容器 view
        convertView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_pegawai, null);

        //建構listItem內容view
        viewTag = new ViewTag(
                (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_namapegawai),
                (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_pegawai));

        //設置容器內容
        convertView.setTag(viewTag);
    } else {
        viewTag = (ViewTag) convertView.getTag();
    }
```

Comment: What exception occurred? Give brief!!!

Comment: There is no `CheckBox` in your code above . Whats the point ?

Comment: sorry i have typo on my code. i already update code upside..

Answer (score 0):

complete code

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    public static ArrayList<Model> modelArrayList;
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model> modelArrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        CustomAdapter.modelArrayList = modelArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return modelArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return modelArrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_select, null, true);

            holder.checkBox = convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            holder.tvName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
            holder.Tvnumber = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView8);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            // the getTag returns the viewHolder object set as a tag to the view
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.tvName.setText(modelArrayList.get(position).getName());
        holder.Tvnumber.setText(modelArrayList.get(position).getPhone());

        holder.checkBox.setChecked(modelArrayList.get(position).getSelected());

        holder.checkBox.setTag(R.integer.btnplusview, convertView);
        holder.checkBox.setTag(position);
        holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                View tempview = (View) holder.checkBox.getTag(R.integer.btnplusview);
                TextView tv = tempview.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
                Integer pos = (Integer) holder.checkBox.getTag();
                if (modelArrayList.get(pos).getSelected()) {
                    modelArrayList.get(pos).setSelected(false);
                } else {
                    modelArrayList.get(pos).setSelected(true);
                }
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        protected CheckBox checkBox;
        private TextView tvName;
        private TextView Tvnumber;

    }

}
```

Comment: your code use recyclerview and i'm use listview do you have any tutorial?

Comment: this is for list view .

Comment: i just edited the answer and have posted the complete adapter .

Comment: when i tryed your code, error on holder after i solve these error i found code to point  in a direction recyclerview. so code above make it recyclerview.

Comment: CustomAdapter  customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(GetContacts.this, modelArrayList);
                listview.setAdapter(customAdapter);